# Pyspark : Multiple join condition with cast type as string

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark SQL , i would need to cast as_of_date to string and do a multiple inner join with 3 tables and select all rows & columns in table1  , 2 and 3 after join . Example table schema as shown below

```
Tablename : Table_01 alias t1

Column      | Datatype
as_of_date  | String
Tablename   | String
Credit_Card | String


Tablename : Table_02   alias t2

Column        | Datatype
as_of_date    | INT
Customer_name | String
tablename     | string

Tablename : Table_03   alias t3

Column        | Datatype
as_of_date    | String
tablename     | String 
address       | String
```

Join use-case :

```
t1.as_of_date = t2.as_of_date AND t1.tablename = t2.tablename
t2.as_of_date = t3.as_of_date AND t2.tablename = t3.tablename
```

Tables are already created in hive,  i am doing a spark transformation on top of this tables and i am converting as_of_date in table_02 as string.

There are 2 approach i have thought of , but i am unsure which is the best approach

Approach 1:

```
df = spark.sql("select t1.*,t2.*,t3.* from table_1 t1 where cast(t1.as_of_date as string) inner join table_t2 t2 on t1.as_of_date = t2.as_of_date AND t1.tablename = t2.tablename inner join table_03 t3 on t2.as_of_date = t3.as_of_date and t2.tablename = t3.tablename")
```

Approach 2:

```
df_t1 = spark.sql("select * from table_01");
df_t2 = spark.sql("select * from table_02");
df_t3 = spark.sql("select * from table_03");

## Cast as_of_date as String if dtype as of date is int 
if dict(df_t2.dtypes)["as_of_date"] == 'int':
        df_t1["as_of_date"].cast(cast(StringType())
                                  
## Join Condition 
df = df_t1.alias('t1').join(df_t2.alias('t2'),on="t1.tablename=t2.tablename AND t1.as_of_date = t2.as_of_date", how='inner').join(df_t3.alias('t3'),on="t2.as_of_date = t3.as_of_date AND t2.tablename = t3.tablename",how='inner').select('t1.*,t2.*,t3.*')
```

I feel that using approach 2 is long winded, i would need some advice on which approach should i go with as for easy maintenance and the scripts used

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Spark SQL directly as below. You can cast every as_of_date column from all tables as a string regardless of its data type. You want to cast integer into string, but if you also cast string into a string, it does no harm.

```
df = spark.sql("""
    select t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
    from t1
    join t2 on string(t1.as_of_date) = string(t2.as_of_date) AND t1.tablename = t2.tablename
    join t3 on string(t2.as_of_date) = string(t3.as_of_date) AND t2.tablename = t3.tablename
""")
```